# The highest density of water

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, water, density

If temperature is decreased, volume decreases. so density increases. But in case of water, its density increases up to 277 K, then decreases. Why does this happen? Why 277 K is water's highest density?

Comment: You might like to put some more detail into what kind of answer you want. I mean, the answer, at the most basic level, is clearly that at temperatures lower than 277K, the lowest free energy state of ice / water is attained by a density that increases, and above 277K, this lowest free energy state is reached at a density that decreases with temperature. But I suspect you want to know *why* the lowest free energy state is so.

Comment: [This unusual negative thermal expansion is attributed to strong, orientation-dependent, intermolecular interactions and is also observed in molten silica.(25)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Properties_of_water#Density_of_water_and_ice)

Comment: Strictly speaking, that's only the highest density at normal pressure. One can increase the density quite a bit by increasing the pressure. See e.g. http://www.nature.com/srep/2012/121008/srep00713/fig_tab/srep00713_F3.html.