# Does the density of water ice (any form of water ice) near 0K exceed the density of water at 277.15K?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, water

In a question brought up by my chemistry class, the most we have determined is that the stability of most forms of ice decreases as the temperature decreases. What does this loss of stability do to the density of the ice (secondary question)?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78414/ and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/142192/

Comment: Saying these are related is a bit of a stretch.

Comment: Both those posts discuss the density of water & ice, no? How is that *not* related to your title question? (which you appear to imply is your initial question, given the label to the only question in the body as a "secondary question").

Comment: We have already established these facts in class, perhaps I can call them "contextual information"...

Comment: ...how is contextual information different from related?

Comment: One is necessary for understanding what the question is asking. The other isn't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25898/discussion-between-jack-lam-and-kyle-kanos).